# Rails unable to connect mongolab's mogodb using mongoid version 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have created simple rails application with mongodb backend. I have no issues in connecting my rails 4 application with local mongodb database. But I cannot connect mongolab's mongodb service. I have the following code in mongoid.yml

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: trial_db
      hosts:
        -   dsXXXXXX.mlab.com:53216/trial_db
      username: username
      password: password
      options:
        pool_size: 50
```

I am used following versions ruby, rails, mongoid
Rails version - 4.2
Ruby Version - 2.1.5
mongoid version - 4

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid 4 is not compatible with MongoDB 3.x. mLab Sandboxes are currently running MongoDB 3.2. To use mLab with your app, you'll need to use Mongoid 5 or 6: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/mongoid/#ruby-mongoid-tutorial